# WooCommerce Custom Fields not being stored, woocommerce_checkout_process failing when there are characters in the field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I simply don't understand what's happening. I have tried so many examples on stack overflow and not a single one, even when copied and pasted directly are working.

I'm trying to add custom fields to my checkout. This is working however no matter if I write manually into the text box or textarea or have javascript fill in the boxes the 'woocommerce_checkout_process' will always fail as if the box is empty and even if I pull that code out the order will have empty data where the field data should be stored. I have honestly tried every option I have located on the internet. This is infuriating as it seems to be working for everyone else. I don't know if this is a database security issue from my host that I'm unaware of, a bug in the latest version of WooCommerce, an issue with Divi. There have been no solutions, I'm genuinely hoping that someone knows something that I can't locate.

I have also tried with a single field in 'woocommerce_after_order_notes' still to no avail.

The code is as follows and was pulled directly from WC site, I've tried every modification I could find from other forums:

```
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Wallet Info') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'checkbox_address', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('I have a Wallet'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'checkbox_address' ));
    
    woocommerce_form_field( 'address_field', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Wallet Address'),
        'placeholder'   => __('000'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'address_field' ));
    
    woocommerce_form_field( 'chosen_images', array(
        'type'          => 'textarea',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Chosen NFTs from above'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'chosen_images' ));

    echo '</div>';

}

/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['chosen_images'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
}


/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['chosen_images'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'chosen_images', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['chosen_images'] ) );
    }
}

/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('chosen_images').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'chosen_images', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Thanks in advance. I appreciate anyone who looks into this with me. Cheers!

Comment: Try to disable all plugins to see if it is working

Comment: Tried this. Same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
update_post_meta( $order_id, 'chosen_images', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['chosen_images'] ) );
```

With

```
update_post_meta( $order_id, 'chosen_images', sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['chosen_images'] ) );
```

sanitize_text_field() is used for type="text" not for texarea.

Full Updated Code

```
/**
     * Add the field to the checkout
     */
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

    function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

        echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Wallet Info') . '</h2>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'checkbox_address', array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('I have a Wallet'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'checkbox_address' ));
        
        woocommerce_form_field( 'address_field', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Wallet Address'),
            'placeholder'   => __('000'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'address_field' ));
        
        woocommerce_form_field( 'chosen_images', array(
            'type'          => 'textarea',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Chosen NFTs from above'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'chosen_images' ));

        echo '</div>';

    }

    /**
     * Process the checkout
     */
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

    function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
        // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
        if ( ! $_POST['chosen_images'] )
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
    }


    /**
     * Update the order meta with field value
     */
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

        function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
            if ( ! empty( $_POST['chosen_images'] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $order_id, 'chosen_images', sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['chosen_images'] ) );
            }
        }

    /**
     * Display field value on the order edit page
     */
    add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

    function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('chosen_images').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'chosen_images', true ) . '</p>';
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32114244)

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this code
Reference: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-custom-checkout-field-php/

Comment: You can check updated answer. Its working. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, good find but doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. I tried with a text field multiple times but still didn't work. The issue seems to be that when the field is filled in the value never gets updated so it never gets stored. I'm using woocommerce_checkout_process to check and see if the field has characters and even if it does this throws an error that it's blank. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: still error is there? or empty field is saved?

Comment: The error is simply the woocommerce_checkout_process saying the field is empty (even though it’s not empty) and I can’t checkout until something has been added to the field. If I remove the check, the blank field is stored

Comment: I have updated answer with full updated code. It is tested and working fine.